# Enable Mismatch namespace warnings in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm facing a bug I had never seen before. Visual Studio doesn't tell me when an object does exist into 2 namespaces.
Also, I've already found a few errors into the project I'm working on, but I can't identify where the other errors might be.

eg :

http://cdn.imghack.se/medium/a95f269da3f3931f18db1015d8ca7783.png

http://cdn.imghack.se/medium/7b8303be920e33740995db88f668a4c4.png

As far as I know, VS should send a warning message in this case, but this doesn't happen. What should I do to activate it?

(before you ask, I've binged it before posting here)

Comment: It only warns you on ambigous references when both namespaces are used. So when there is no warning, then there is probably no using statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio will only warn you if the reference is ambiguous.  In your example, your [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) directive has an alias of `NF1` for one of the namespaces, so that gets rid of the ambiguity.